# Dynamically create a tuple with all the same type and a known number of elements

Tags: c#, dictionary, tuples

I am looking to dynamically create tuples of a given size that have all the same type.

So if I wanted a tuple of strings of size three I would get Tuple<string, string, string>

I have tried both to pass strings into the angle brackets for Tuple like this:

```
string foo = "string, string, string";
Tuple<foo> testTuple = Tuple<foo>(~parameters~);
```

and to pass an array of types into the angle brackets like this:

```
List<Type> types = new List<Type>() {"".GetType(), "".GetType(), "".GetType()};
Tuple<types> testTuple = Tuple<foo>(~parameters~);
```

Neither one of these worked. Does anyone know how to make the described dynamic tuples?

(The reason I want to do this is to use tuples inside of a dictionary like

```
Dictionary<Tuple<# strings>, int> testDictionary = new Dictionary<Tuple<x # strings>, int>();
```

Using tuples here is more useful than HashSets because the comparison in tuples is by components instead of by reference so that if I have

```
Tuple<string, string> testTuple1 = new Tuple<string, string>("yes", "no");
Tuple<string, string> testTuple2 = new Tuple<string, string>("yes", "no");
Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, string> testDictionary = new Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, string>() {
    {testTuple1, "maybe"}
};
Console.WriteLine(testDict[testTuple2]);
```

it writes "maybe". If you run this same test with HashSets, it throws an error. If there is a better way to accomplish this same thing, that would also be useful.)

Comment: You appear to have some external requirements that you're trying to cram into framework types (tuple, dictionary).  Don't.  Create custom types that hold the data you need held in the way you need it held.

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this using reflection:

```
    public static object GetTuple<T>(params T[] values)
    {
        Type genericType = Type.GetType("System.Tuple`" + values.Length);
        Type[] typeArgs = values.Select(_ => typeof(T)).ToArray();
        Type specificType = genericType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
        object[] constructorArguments = values.Cast<object>().ToArray();
        return Activator.CreateInstance(specificType, constructorArguments);
    }
```

That will give you a tuple for a variable number of elements.

Comment: You can cast it to tuple instead of object to at least get the `Tuple<,,>` type back at compile time: `return (Tuple<object, object, object>)Activator.CreateInstance(specificType, values);` and return `Tuple<object, object, object>` instead of `object`.

Comment: @Quantic that assumes you know how many param arguments you'll be taking... which I assume we don't.

Comment: Ah I see, I somehow missed the fact that the number of items is itself dynamic and you got around that with using the string `"System.Tuple\`" + values.Length`.

Answer (score 1):

"Does anyone know how to make the described dynamic tuples?"

You can just use `Tuple.Create()`. For a [3-tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387244(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var tupleOfStrings = Tuple.Create("string1", "string2", "string3");
var tupleOfInts = Tuple.Create(1, 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make custom type with `List<string>` inside (or `List<T>` if you want generic solution)

Override `object.Equals`: Use `Enumerable.SequenceEqual` for inner list in your custom class

Override `object.GetHashCode()` in order to use your type in dictionary